# Error loading component "com_jce"

Tags: mysql, web-services, joomla, joomla3.0

I recently put a beta version of my website up as a subdomain of the currently running site. I was able to get it kickstarted and working, but there is a constant warning that I cant figure out. I updated joomla to 3.6.2 and the error is still there.

Thanks for any help!

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFRJp.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Finish Removing JCE Editor**

It looks like the JCE Editor component has been removed but some JCE plugins remain. To complete the removal of JCE Editor, go to `Extensions -> Manage -> Manage`, search for "JCE", and uninstall all the remaining JCE plugins.

**Or Install Latest Version Over Existing Installation**

Alternatively, install the latest version of [JCE Editor](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jce) by downloading and installing over the existing installation via `Extensions -> Manage -> Install`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the JCE component through phpmyadmin. Some remnants are there in `#__extensions` of Joomla database. Search for the term JCE in phpmyadmin Joomla database. You will find some extensions of JCE. Select all (**but be careful not to delete any extension that is not part of JCE**) and then delete them.

Note: Better take **BACKUP** of your entire Joomla database before editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Extensions-->Discover** and see if JCE is not installed/corrupted/whatever (you might have to refresf cache to see it)

or:

**Uninstall/Reinstall** JCE editor and its plugins